# How to find the Jacobian of a matrix vector product?

Tags: matrices, vectors, partial-derivative, products, jacobian

If $H(t)$ is a given two dimensional Hamiltonian matrix , $Y$ is a vector (spinor). 
Defined is the function $F(t,Y)= H(t)Y$. What is the Jacobian of F(t,Y). In some numerical method I need to find the approximate Jacobian defined by $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(t_0, Y_0)$ which I am using in an implicit Runge-Kutta scheme.
For example suppose that the problem is like this:
\begin{equation}
F(t, Y) = \begin{pmatrix} t^2 & t+5\\ exp(t^2) & ln(t) \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
How can I find the Jacobian $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}$?

Comment: Denote the columns of $H(t)$ by $h_k(t)$, $k=1,2$. Then $F(t,Y) = Y_1h_1(t)+Y_2h_2(t)$. So, $\partial F/\partial Y_k = h_k(t)$ for $k=1,2$. So, $\partial F/\partial Y = [h_1(t),h_2(t)] =  H(t)$.

Comment: Ok. This is what I tried  in the code but it didn't work. Now I am sure it is the code! Thanks!